# How to create a Windows Performance Monitor Application

Tags: asp.net, web, performance

I need to create my own application that is similar windows performance monitor. I want to monitor the DQL using asp.net. But i don't know where to start. I already research but no luck.

Comment: As far I as understand, you want to create a web application?

Comment: What is "the DQL"? Which part are you actually having trouble with?

Comment: @KonradKokosa yes I need to create a web application that will show side by side the Disk Queue Length of our servers. This way we can monitor it. We already had ORION but the version is outdated and doesn't have Performance monitor. We can't afford to upgrade the version.

Comment: @iamkristher so follow my suggestions below about used technologies and start implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using below components (but still remember, it is only a suggestion) to start from:

- [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class - to access performance counter data
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) - to create a website
- [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5) - to create a backend Hub for client notifications of data gathered by `PerformanceCounter` class
- [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) - to create charts control

Comment: thanks for this. I now have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

What is your planned usage of this application? If you are planning to use it for your organization then you might want to consider SaaS solution that allows you to plug in your collector.

You have better uptime on the monitoring application because that monitoring service is the last thing you want to go down. You are probably more familiar with how to monitor DQL than to create an application that does charting and alerting. You should be able to get something going within days instead of weeks.

Monitoring is normally composed of collecting, storing and charting. A good SaaS monitoring tool will do well with storing and charting and you need to look for ones with plugin framework that allow you to decide what to collect.